# How to query db on multiple terms extracted from single string

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

This is the my GET request for subject.

`http://localhost:8000/subject=English%2CArt`

Its treats English and Arts as a single subject,but it should be separate. Any idea how can i search these subjects individually ?

```
 $students= Student::with(['subscriptions' => function($query){
            $query->orderBy('subscriptions.id','desc');
          }])
           ->whereHas('subjects', function ($query) use ($subject) {

              $query->where('name', 'like', "%{$subject}%")->orderByRaw('RAND()');

             })->distinct()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use explode to seperate the subject from the url into 2 subject, in this case english and art after that you can loop the subject

```
   $subjects = explode(",", $subject);
    foreach($subjects as $subject){

        $students= Student::with(['subscriptions' => function($query){
                    $query->orderBy('subscriptions.id','desc');
                  }])
                   ->whereHas('subjects', function ($query) use ($subject) {

                      $query->where('name', 'like', "%{$subject}%")->orderByRaw('RAND()');

                     })->distinct()->get();
    }
```

maybe i think you can share your database schema in here so we can help, you can also use whereIn to filter the data of the subjects